# How can I answer "Yes" to an apache installation using Vagrantfile for automatic creation of a VM?

Tags: debian, software-installation, vagrant

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :nodo1 do |nodo1|
    nodo1.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
    nodo1.vm.hostname = "nodo1"
    nodo1.vm.network :public_network,:bridge=>"wlp3s0"
    nodo1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.1.1.101"
    nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo ip route del default",
     run: "always"
    nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1",
     run: "always"
    nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1",
     run: "always"
    nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo modprobe ip_tables",
     run: "always"
    nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.114 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.102:80",
     run: "always"
  end
  config.vm.define :nodo2 do |nodo2|
    nodo2.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
    nodo2.vm.hostname = "nodo2"
    nodo2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.1.1.102"
    nodo2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt update",
     run: "always"
    nodo2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt install apache2",
     run: "always"
  end
end
```

These are contents of my Vagrantfile. But the whole code is not important for my question (I just wanted you to see the whole code so that may help you), just these lines of code:

```
nodo2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt update",
 run: "always"
nodo2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt install apache2",
 run: "always"
```

If I execute a `vagrant up`, all works perfectly but for those lines. The problem is that when it's trying to install apache, the program asks you to write `y` to complete the installation, and it initiates the machines but with an error saying that the installation process was aborted.

## MY QUESTION IS

How can I make this process fully automatic and answer yes to the installation?

## EDIT

I have another question directly related to my code. The scenario is composed by 2 machines, 1 with access to internet, another connected to the first but without internet + web server. In the first machine I configure DNAT so that I can access the web server.
**BUT**
Is it necessary to load this module on the first machine (the one doing DNAT) in order for DNAT to work?:

```
nodo1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo modprobe ip_tables",
 run: "always"
```

Comment: Add -y to the sudo apt install command.

Comment: where exactly? @ajgringo619

Comment: `nodo2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt install -y apache2", run: "always"`